# Mysql after deleting record decrement other ID's

Tags: php, mysql

I have the database where i save my records. The records was saved as 
ID, name

example

1. Nick
2. Name
3. Username

Now when i delete the record with id 2. in my database it remains as 
1. Nick
3. Username
I want that when i delete one record from database other id's automatic decrement for one value so i get.
1. Nick
2. Username 
Do you understand my question. Sry for bad english

Button delete code

```
if(isset($_POST['tipkaobrisi'])) // pritisnuta tipka obrisi
{
    $obrisankorisnik = $_POST['obrisi'];
    if ( $obrisankorisnik == '' )echo "<div align='center'>Unesite korisnika kojeg  zelite obrisati!</div>";
    else
    {
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM Korisnici WHERE Korisnik ='$obrisankorisnik'");
        echo "<div align='center'>Korisnik obrisan<br><br></div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot imagine why you would want to reorder your unique IDs. There is literally no reason for that. You can always order your records at select however you like.

Comment: You don't want to do that.  The ids are for relating to other tables.  If you change an id in one table you have to change them all.  Big mess, lots of overhead.  There is no problem with missing ids.

Comment: I dont want in my database i dont have any record under id 2. That is the mostly reason of this

Comment: Please, don't do that.

Comment: what is the idea behind that. what do you want to achieve by doing this????

Comment: Did this question just get a up-vote, or am i hallucinating, again...

Comment: This is a BAD idea. You do not change ids after they've been assigned. The DB doesn't care if they're sequential and/or have "holes". It can handle holes/non-sequentiality just fine. You're probably worried about DISPLAYING those ids. That's not the db's job.

Comment: That's not how unique IDs are supposed to work, give yourself a shake!

Answer (score 2):

That is not the intention of most ID columns. However, you can mimick this functionality by modifying the statement you use to access those records.

E.g. rather than using the ID value, use the following

```
select  @rownum:=@rownum+1 as ID, name from users, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r order by id;
```

It will give each record returned a number, with no gaps. Depending on what you want this for, that may be enough. If you would like to treat this new ID value as *the* ID value, create a view and access your elements based on that, like so:

```
CREATE VIEW users_view as select  @rownum:=@rownum+1 as ID, name from users, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r order by id;
```

at which point you can SELECT * FROM users_view WHERE ID = $id and have it work as usual. So long as you never insert a new record that is not auto incremented, this scheme should work.

Keep in mind that deleting anybody changes a bunch of IDs, so it's not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

After listening other programer's advice's. I decide that i don't want to edit my ID's.

Thanks to all for participating.

Comment: Pretty good decision. But know the solution, only way (I guess) is drop the column and create it again programatically.

Comment: ^ Which would have astronomical overheads :(